# Display empty textbox based on selected value from form_for select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add additional field "department" to the existing devise signup template. I am trying to implement a drop-down which consists a list of departments like dept1, dept2...., not_listed. When not_listed is selected I want to display the textbox where a user can enter custom department and store the value of department in database rather than Not Listed.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="border-form-div">

<h3 class="text-center">Create a new account</h3>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Email address", class: "form-control", required: false %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", class: "form-control", required: false %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Confirm password", class: "form-control", required: false %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select :department, options_for_select(["dept1", "dept2", "dept3", "dept4", "Not Listed"]), class: "form-control", html: { id: "dept-id"}  %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul><%= f.text_field :department, :placeholder => "enter your department", html: {id: "not_listed_1"} %></ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dept-id').change(function() {
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if(selected == 'Not Listed'){
        $('#not_listed_1').show();
      }
      else{
        $('#not_listed_1').hide();
      }
    });
    });
  </script>
  <br>

  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-primary", :id => "page[sign_up]" %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-default", :id => "page[cancel]" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am not good with jquery. Can some one point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What's the problem with the above code?

Comment: The text box appers when the page is loaded. I want that text box to appear only if not listed is selected in the drop down

Comment: Hide the textbox by default using `html: {id: "not_listed_1", style:"display:none"}` OR add the `class: "hidden"` for the textbox

Comment: @Vijai: That is not working. The textfield still appears.

Comment: @tpdietz: The text-field should not appear when loading the page. It should appear only after selecting the not listed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which works for me and I tested it. You will just need to add and modify couple of lines of code, and it will work for you.

First I added field department to devise model: `rails g migration User department:string` and `run db:migrate`.

Then I made custom registration controller (which extends Devise's one):

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:department, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:department, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

My route file looks like this now:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Then I generated Devise views: `rails generate devise:views` and I opened Devise's views registration file from: **app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb** to add new form fields:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.select :department, options_for_select(["dept1", "dept2", "dept3", "dept4", "Not Listed"], :selected => f.object.department), class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div id="show_dep" style="display: none">
    Please enter your department: <br />
      <%= f.text_field :department, :placeholder => "enter your department", html: {id: "#show_dep"} %>
    </div>
```

And the last snippet of code is jQuery: ( You can add to application.js )

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#user_department").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Not Listed") {
            $("#show_dep").show();
        } else {
            $("#show_dep").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I checked in rails console,(`User.last`), and :department field was populated with data from users input.

I hope it helps,

Cheers!

Comment: @draghori, have you solved your problem with empty text box?